# Ruby on Rails: reverse lookup of array list of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, processing-efficiency

i have a model with a user selectable option that is set up in an array on the model.

```
def Pie < ActiveRecored::Base
    def self.sel_options
      [ [ "Apple Blueberry", "AB" ],
        [ "Cranberry Date", "CD" ] ]
    end
end
```

while the short string is retrieved from elsewhere and stored in the database, i would like to display the longer string when showing the object.  e.g. in the view use:

```
Pie.display_customeor_choice[@pie_flavor]
```

i don't want to hard code the reverse hash, but if i create a display_options method that converts the array to a hash with reverse mapping will it run the conversion every time display_options is called?  this could be resource intensive with large arrays that are converted a lot, is there a way to create the reverse hash once when the app is started and never again?  (using rails 3 and ruby 1.9.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [Array#rassoc](http://www.rubybrain.com/api/ruby-1.8.7/doc/index.html?a=M002112&name=rassoc)

```
Pie.display_customeor_choice.rassoc("@pie_flavor")
```

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what i was looking for but somehow overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it:

```
def Pie < ActiveRecored::Base

  def self.sel_options
    [ [ "Apple Blueberry", "AB" ],
      [ "Cranberry Date", "CD" ] ]
  end

  def self.display_customeor_choice
    unless @options
      @options = {}
      sel_options.each { |items| @options[items.last] = items.first }
    end
    @options
  end       

end
```

This guarantees it's going to be loaded only once on production (or other environments where cache_classes is set to true) but always reloads on development mode, making it simpler for you to change and see the changes.

Comment: this is a good thought too, a better work-around than what i had.